# Qt-Building a project for UWP

Tags: qt, serial-port, raspberry-pi, uwp, windowsiot

I have windows 10 (64 bit) and Qt 5.7 (32 bit) and Visual Studio 2015 on my computer.
I installed UWP arm7(MSVC2015), UWP X86(MSVC2015) and UWP X64(MSVC2015) from Qt 5.9 via Qt online installer.
I can run project in any computers with windows 7, 8, 10.
But I have error while building same project for UWP.
Compile Output:
error: Unknown module(s) in QT: serialport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Qt Serial Port` module [doesn't support](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmodules.html#qt-add-ons) Qt's [WinRT platform](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/winrt-support.html).

To clarify how `WinRT` related to `Windows 10 UWP`, Qt's [WinRT platform](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/winrt-support.html) targets devices running [Windows 10](http://Windows%2010) as well as Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows RT.

Comment: I want to use for windows iot on raspberry.